# Updating Java with Solaris zones

Tags: java, solaris, zones

I am running a server with a global zone and four local zones. The global zone provides the database server, and the four local zones run instances of Tomcat with a client application (different one per zone).

When I built the server, I installed Java 1.6 on the global zone, then created the local zones - so they all have Java 1.6 on them.

Now I need to upgrade to Java 1.8. I have done this on another Solaris server with no zones and have had no problems, but I am wondering how to handle the zones with the upgrade.

I plan to upgrade Java on the global zone, but what about the other zones? I require Java 1.8 on all the zones, which is why I'm upgrading the global zone.

What I'm asking is how to manage the upgrade with the other zones. Do I shut them down first? Are there commands to propogate the new Java version to the other zones once the global zone is done?

I've searched but so far have come up empty. Thanks to all for assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer - the Java package for Solaris is 'zone aware' so you can update Java to the latest version on the global zone and it will also update Java on the other running zones.

Answer (score 0):

You may not like this answer but I've never understood the benefit of installing Java via a package manager. After all the JRE (or the JDK for that matter) is simply a compressed archive before it is installed.

Here are the simple steps to install without using a package manager:

1. Download JRE package (replace URL as appropriate for your platform an desired JRE version)

   ```
   wget \
       --no-cookies \
       --no-check-certificate \
       --header "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" \
       http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u60-b27/jre-8u60-solaris-x64.tar.gz
   ```
2. Unpack into where you want it. (e.g. `/opt/java`) or whatever
3. If you have multiple JREs installed under that location then create symlinks, e.g. `jre7` would point to your preferred JRE 7 version, etc.

You'll gain much more control that way as opposed to using a package manager. Different applications on the same host can use different version of the JRE if they so prefer.